# Firebase query array or objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been struggling with creating a firebase query all day!

The below query returns the data as an array from my Firebase realtime database:

```
exports.getCountry = () => {
  return database
    .ref("/countries")
    .once("value")
    .then(data => data.val());
};
```

This returns the below from the database in the format Array of Objects,

```
[
    {"id":1, "country":"singapore", "population":15000000},
    {"id":2, "country":"hongkong", "population":12000000},
    {"id":2, "country":"vietnam", "population":2250000}
]
```

However I want to query the database to just return one record, something along the lines of

```
exports.getCountry = () => {
  return database
    .ref("/countries")
    .where('id'===1)
    .once("value")
    .then(data => data.val());
};
```

would return a single line from my database:

```
{"id":1, "country":"singapore", "population":15000000}
```

however I can't get this to work! It should be simple, but I can't get it to play ball!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced [these Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-complex-queries) on complex queries.

Piecing together the examples they provide, I think your query should look something like:

```
var ref = db.ref("countries");

ref.orderByChild("id").equalTo(1).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach( data => {
        console.log(data.val());
    });
});
```

*untested

EDIT:

The docs I linked are to the admin SDK, if you are doing this on the front end with JavaScript, it should still work. The JavaScript SDK appears to have the same query structure - shown in [these docs for the JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) too.